# How can I get a datagridview to display a list<int>/list(of integer)?

Tags: .net, generics, datagridview

seems simple enough, I want to take a generics list of integers and display them on a datagridview. google comes back with plenty of results on displaying custom classes in a datagridview, but not a list of int. when I just submit the list as the datasource, nothing shows.

I tried using

```
dim _CheckIns as new list(of integer)
_checkins.add(1577)
_checkins.add(1999)
Dim bl As New System.ComponentModel.BindingList(Of Integer)(Me._CheckIns)
me._dg.datasource=bl
```

then tried bindingsource to go with the binding list

```
dim bs as new BindingSource()
bs.datasource=bl
me._dg.datasrouce=bs
```

No luck so far.

Comment: I can read c# so answers in either language would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Won't be that easy, the databinding mechanism looks for properties and Int32 doesn't have any. You can test it with a List< int?>, it'll show HasValue and Value colums.

So you'll have to wrap it in a class:

```
class MyInt
{
   public int Value { get; private set; }
   public MyInt(int v) { Value = v; }
}
```

I made it immutable to comply with current best practices.

Comment: oh neat, I read once that you could make the Set private, didn't pay attention to the syntax, and now see lots of places I can use that trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try databinding bs after giving it a datasource

```
bs.DataBind()
```

Comment: I'm not finding a member of BindingSource, BindingList, nor datagridview called DataBind()?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the grid is the object that needs to be databound:

```
me._dg.DataSource = bs
me._dg.DataBind()
```

Comment: I'm not finding a member of BindingSource, BindingList, nor datagridview called DataBind()? This is a windows forms application, I do recall a databind in asp.net perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to this and just ended up converting to a List

```
var lstInts = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var lstConvertToStrings = lstInts.Select(x => new {NumberAsString = x.ToString()}).ToList();
```